# how to write the query without using IN operator?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to write without using IN operator below query:

```
select q_event_seq, rownum.....
from notify_request 
where q_event_seq in (
    select q_event_seq 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT q_event_seq, DENSE_RANK() over (order by q_start, contact_gid) digest_rank 
        FROM NOTIFY_REQUEST
        WHERE q_state = 'QUEUED' 
        order by digest_rank
        )
    where digest_rank <= 10
    ) 
ORDER BY q_start, contact_gid ;
```

Comment: Is this homework or a puzzle?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can turn your IN condition to a SELECT DISTINCT q_event_seq ... then join to it.

But why would you?  That's what the database is doing anyway.  What's the rationale for removing the IN?

Also, why are you giving index hints?  Is that really necessary (it's certainly not for asking a question).  The whole question smacks of trying to out-guess the query optimiser.